# Git error "fatal: 'my_blog_tmp' does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git

I'm very new to Git and I've been following this online tutorial for converting my existing SVN repository to a Git repository and am stuck at the final hurdle.

http://www.jonmaddox.com/2008/03/05/cleanly-migrate-your-subversion-repository-to-a-git-repository/

On the last step of the tutorial it says to do this:

git clone my_blog_tmp my_blog

However, when I do, I get the following error:

fatal: 'my_blog_tmp' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Some points:

1) I'm entering the above command from within the "my_blog_tmp" directory
2) I've tried entering "git init" to make sure Git is initialised inside the "my_blog_tmp" folder but no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `git clone` is the *path* to your repo. So let's say that `my_blog_tmp` was at `/tmp/git/my_blog_tmp`. Then, to clone, you'd go to the directory where you want to clone the repo, and do:

```
$ git clone /tmp/git/my_blog_tmp my_blog
```